# PROC SQL with GROUP command extremely slow. Why? Workaround possible?

Tags: plot, sas, sas-macro

I have a MACRO which takes a data set D and essentially outputs k disjoint datasets, D_1,...,D_k. The value k is not fixed and depends on properties of the data that are not known in advance. We can assume that k is not larger than 10, though.

The dataset D contains the variables x and y, and I want to overlay the line/scatter plots of x and y for each of D_i over each other. In my particular case x is time, and I want to see the output y for each D_i and compare them to each other.

Hopefully that was clear.

How can I do this? I don't know k in advance, so I need some sort of %do loop. But it doesn't seem that I can put a do loop inside "proc sgplot".

I might be able to make a macro that includes a very long series of commands, but I'm not sure.

How can I overlay these plots in SAS?

**EDIT:** I am including for reference why I am trying to avoid doing a PROC SGPLOT with the GROUP clause. I tried the following code and it is taking over 30 minutes to compute (I canceled the calculation after this, so I don't know how long it will actually take). PROC SQL runs quite quickly, the program is stuck on PROC SGPLOT.

```
    proc sql;
    create table dataset as select    
        date, product_code, sum(num_of_records) as total_rec
        from &filename
            group by product_code, data
                order by product_code, date
    ;
quit;

PROC SGPLOT Data = dataset;
    scatter x = date   y = total_rec/group=product_code;
    title "Total records by product code";
run;
```

The number of observations in the file is 76,000,000.

Comment: Can you make an example `&filename` dataset - to show the frequency of product_Code and such?  Just `data mydata; do product_code = 1 to 10000; do date = 1 to 7600; (some way to generate sensible x y); output;end end; run;` or something along those lines.  Something that matches approximately how many product codes and how many rows per product code.

Comment: I get stuck on a simple case there are two product codes and where half of the data has one product code, the other half has the other product code. Is this enough?

Comment: If it reproduces your issue, that is perfectly fine.  Something that takes 30-60 minutes or whatever for you to run that you want to make faster.

Comment: Ok, I will do this. I will only have time in an hour, but will get to it. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is either change your macro to produce *one* dataset with a variable `d_i` (or whatever you can logically name it) which identifies which dataset it would've gone to (or identifies it with whatever determines what dataset it would've gone to), or post-macro combine the datasets.

Then, you can use `group` to overlay your plots.  So for example:

```
data my_data;
  call streaminit(7);
  do d_i = 1 to 5;
    y = 10;    
    x = 0;
    output;
    do x = 1 to 10;
      y + round(rand('Uniform')*3,.1)-1.5;
      output;
    end;
  end;
run;

proc sgplot data=my_data;
  series x=x y=y/group=d_i;
run;
```

Comment: The whole reason I am doing it this way is because my dataset is so massive that plotting using Group is taking absurdly long. Proc sql is a much faster way to sort the data and then graph it separately.

Comment: I can't undownvote, I can only upvote. And I'm not sure if you've answered my question. I have an enormous dataset (I work for a large corporation). I don't know why, but proc sgplot with the group command takes on the order of an hour to finish. On the other hand, splitting the dataset in sql by the same grouping is very very fast. I want to exploit this. That is my question.

Comment: In any event, I think this is the only answer you're going to get in SAS.  There's not a functionality analagous to R's additive graphing (i.e. where you can `plot` one vector then `plot` another and they add to the same chart).  Everything needs to be in the same dataset.  I think that even if there were a way to do this (plot several plots on top of each other from different datasets) this would be the fastest method, as it requires only one opening.

Comment: Can you add to the question the details of size here?  That's pretty important to your question, I think.  And the code you're currently using that takes an hour (or something analagous).  If you can, make an example dataset like I did above - easiest probably to make just one with a by-group marker like I did, and then any solution that makes multiple datasets can just split on that.

Comment: Sure. Give me a few minutes and I'll modify the question. Thanks for teaching me about undownvoting, I never knew that!

Comment: The slowness is based on how SAS adds points to a graph and the Java functionality that renders it.  You will often see SAS procedures limit the number of points plotted because of this.  Your best bet is to sample the values from the data and plot the sample.  That should give you a representative graph and a smaller number of points to plot.

Comment: @DomPazz, why does SAS plot the full dataset no problem, but struggles for an eternity when you add the GROUP statement? There seems to be some fundamental inefficiency here.

Comment: I added the asked-for details to my question.

Comment: If you have separate datasets you can't plot them on the same graph. Is the SQL step and corresponding multiple proc sgplots actually faster than waiting for this to run? Is it possible to summarize the data in some manner before plotting it. I can't imagine that 76million points on a single graph will be useful and informative.  If you condense multiples it may help.